# Python3 - NameError: name 'seleccionar_rango' is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

Estoy intentando crear un paquete en el que se encuentra el modulo `main.py` y dos carpetas (`Menus` y `Calculos`).

El módulo `main_3.py` contiene:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# main_3.py
# Importación de módulos

import Menus.menu_seleccion_valor 
import Menus.menu_seleccion_rango
import Calculos.importar_excel_3
import Calculos.selec_rango_3
import Calculos.calculo_beneficios_3
import Calculos.analisis_3
import Calculos.graficos_3     
file1 = (seleccionar_valor())    
df1 = importar_excel(file1)
ini, fin = elegir_periodo_analisis(df1)
selec_index, ini, fin = seleccionar_rango(df1, ini, fin)
```

El módulo `selec_rango_3` contiene:

```
def seleccionar_rango(df, ini, fin):
    mask = df['Fecha'] >= "2017-09-05" 
    cols = ["Fecha", "Valor"]
    df_aux = df.loc[mask, cols]
    selec_index  = df[ini:fin]
    print  ("selec_index = ", selec_index )
    return (selec_index, ini, fin )
```

Cuando ejecuto `main_3()`, obtengo el siguiente error:

```
File "E:/Python/Mi_Cartera_funciones/main_3.py", line 24, in <module>
    selec_index, ini, fin = seleccionar_rango(df1, ini, fin)

NameError: name 'seleccionar_rango' is not defined
```

No acabo de entender cuál es mi equivocación.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu estas importando el modulo a traves de import Calculos.selec_rango_3 por lo que debes usar:

```
selec_index, ini, fin = Calculos.selec_rango_3.seleccionar_rango(df1, ini, fin)
```

O puedes usar from:

```
from Calculos.selec_rango_3 import seleccionar_rango
[...]
selec_index, ini, fin = seleccionar_rango(df1, ini, fin)
[...]
```

Comment: Muchas gracias. Usando la opción  "from" funciona correctamente

Comment: @efueyo no olvides marcar mi respuesta como correcta